# Python formatting lists of lists

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

```
def print_game(Guesses, Clues):
    """(list,list) -> display
    Print to display headers, Guess and Clue,
    with the corresponding sublists of the given lists
    >>>print_game(guesses,clues)
    Guesses     Clues
    o o o o     b
    r r r r     b b
    """
    print("Guesses \t Clues")
    for i in range((len(Guesses))):
        print (Guesses[i], end=" ")
    print ("\t", end=" ") 
    for i in range(len(Clues)):
        print (Clues[i], end= " ")
```

I need the function to produce two columns of Guesses and Clues which are going to be lists of lists to print as they are updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Zip* the lists together so you can process the elements in pairs:

```
print("Guesses", "Clues", sep='\t')
for guess, clue in zip(Guesses, Clues):
    print(' '.join(guess), ' '.join(clue), sep='\t')
```

The individual sublists are joined into a single string by using the `str.join()` method.

Demo:

```
>>> guesses = [['o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r']]
>>> clues = [['b'], ['b', 'b']]
>>> def print_game(Guesses, Clues):
...     print("Guesses", "Clues", sep='\t')
...     for guess, clue in zip(Guesses, Clues):
...         print(' '.join(guess), ' '.join(clue), sep='\t')
... 
>>> print_game(guesses, clues)
Guesses Clues
o o o o b
r r r r b b
```

Given the number of values in the `Guesses` sublists, you may want to double up on the tabs.

Comment: it seems to keep coming up as invalid

Comment: i think because of this  sep='\t'

Comment: @Deka: The `sep='\t'` merely puts tabs between the different arguments to `print()`. If your code checker thinks that is invalid, perhaps you shouldn't use tabs but actual spaces instead. `sep='    '` for example.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this besides combining the two lists together

Comment: @Deka: not really. You'll need to process the lists in pairs, `zip()` is the cleanest way of doing that.

Comment: Also the function still seems to be returning an error

Comment: @Deka: the code, as posted and given an *assumption* as to what the input looks like (since you didn't give us anything concrete), works just fine. That's what the demo is for; that is copied from a Python session where I actually ran the code.

Comment: @Deka: you didn't give me any error message, and I am, in spite of my best efforts, not psychic. I cannot see what you see on your screen.

Comment: invalid syntax: None, line 4, pos 34 which is the position of the sep='\t' or sep=' '

Comment: @Deka: what version of Python are you using? Because you were using `print()` as a function in your own question, I was assuming Python 3, so I gave you an answer written for that version.

Comment: I am running Python 3 but it still seems to be producing an error but thanks though

Comment: @Deka: then carefully check your syntax and make sure you are not missing a `)` or have too many of those, etc.

Comment: I have double checked it and ran it through a code checker and it is still that sep='\t' or sep=' ' that seems to be invalid

Comment: @Deka: yet the syntax works just fine. See the [`print()` function documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). And again, I *cannot see what you see* so I cannot see what code you are trying to run *either*.